# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Laravel AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

[Image of the Console Error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvA95.png)

Whereas I am getting the token in postman when using  **headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},**

Comment: add some controller code too..

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when something is printed in browser before sending the response. make sure you dont have any `echo` or `print` in your code before return a json.

Hope this helps